# How to fix this? I am using ejs@3.0.2

Tags: javascript, ejs

```
TypeError: C:\Users\ubanp\Desktop\other\CodingProjects\Discord-Bots\Ratobot-RewriteVersion\dashboard\views\index.ejs:6
    4|     <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/index.css" />

    5| 

 >> 6|     <%- include('includes/header.ejs'); %>

    7| </head>

    8| <body class="d-flex flex-column h-100">

    9|     <%- include('includes/navbar.ejs'); %>


include is not a function
    at index (C:\Users\ubanp\Desktop\other\CodingProjects\Discord-Bots\Ratobot-RewriteVersion\dashboard\views\index.ejs:53:17)
    at tryHandleCache (C:\Users\ubanp\Desktop\other\CodingProjects\Discord-Bots\Ratobot-RewriteVersion\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:255:36)
    at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (C:\Users\ubanp\Desktop\other\CodingProjects\Discord-Bots\Ratobot-RewriteVersion\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:461:10)
    at View.render (C:\Users\ubanp\Desktop\other\CodingProjects\Discord-Bots\Ratobot-RewriteVersion\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:135:8)
    at tryRender (C:\Users\ubanp\Desktop\other\CodingProjects\Discord-Bots\Ratobot-RewriteVersion\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:640:10)
    at Function.render (C:\Users\ubanp\Desktop\other\CodingProjects\Discord-Bots\Ratobot-RewriteVersion\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:592:3)
    at ServerResponse.render (C:\Users\ubanp\Desktop\other\CodingProjects\Discord-Bots\Ratobot-RewriteVersion\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1012:7)
    at C:\Users\ubanp\Desktop\other\CodingProjects\Discord-Bots\Ratobot-RewriteVersion\dashboard\routes\index.js:6:9
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\ubanp\Desktop\other\CodingProjects\Discord-Bots\Ratobot-RewriteVersion\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Users\ubanp\Desktop\other\CodingProjects\Discord-Bots\Ratobot-RewriteVersion\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\ubanp\Desktop\other\CodingProjects\Discord-Bots\Ratobot-RewriteVersion\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\ubanp\Desktop\other\CodingProjects\Discord-Bots\Ratobot-RewriteVersion\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at C:\Users\ubanp\Desktop\other\CodingProjects\Discord-Bots\Ratobot-RewriteVersion\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\ubanp\Desktop\other\CodingProjects\Discord-Bots\Ratobot-RewriteVersion\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (C:\Users\ubanp\Desktop\other\CodingProjects\Discord-Bots\Ratobot-RewriteVersion\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at Function.handle (C:\Users\ubanp\Desktop\other\CodingProjects\Discord-Bots\Ratobot-RewriteVersion\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:174:3)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Include is not a `function`; You can `include includes/header.js` instead.

Comment: Thanks, but I tryed that already didn't work.